# Should the Entity Manager be closed by ourself in EJB?

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, ejb

I am new to EJB. I want to know that the EnityManger should be closed by ourself (`em.close()` )of a stateless or statefull sessionbeans in EJB 3.0 ( may be inside a method where `@preDestroy` annotation is used )? Is it closed by the ejb container, release its resources and we don't need to dwell EnitityManger after retrieving required DB data? What are the services we should stop or close ourselves ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In EJB there is normally no need to do any of that.

An entity manager is by default container managed and its associated persistence context is transaction scoped. This means there is no need to either create or close the entity manager, nor is there any need to begin, commit or rollback anything.

After the method that starts a transaction (which happens transparently as well) completes, the transaction scoped persistence context is guaranteed to be flushed (all outstanding updates are written to the DB) and cleaned (the L1 cache is destroyed) as well as any other resources involved with that entity manager.

A standard example:

```
@Stateless 
public class CustomerService { 

  @PersistenceContext 
  private EntityManager entityManager; 

  public void addCustomer(Customer customer) { 
    entityManager.persist(customer); 
  } 
}
```

*Note that if you really wanted, you could use an application managed entity manager by injecting a factory instead and obtaining the entity manager from it. In that situation you would indeed need to do any closing yourself. If you would also combine this with bean managed transactions and the extended persistence context, you'd be in a situation where even in EJB you'd need to do everything yourself. But this is very rare, and only provided to you as an option. It's not the default.*